# Is there any short and better way to parse a string to Double with exceptions handled?

Tags: java

This is the code that i have written to get the text from the textboxes, parse them to double datatype, and print their product. So, is there any alternative for parsing a string to double with its exceptions handled..?

```
...........
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        try{
            if(ae.getSource()==b1 || ae.getSource()==t2){
                String s1=t1.getText();
                String s2=t2.getText();
                double x=Double.parseDouble(s1);
                double y=Double.parseDouble(s2);
                double z=x*y;
                t3.setText(""+z);
            }
            if(ae.getSource()==b2){
                t1.setText(null);
                t2.setText(null);
                t3.setText(null);
                t1.requestFocus(true);
            }
        }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Please Enter Proper Number in the TextFields");
        }
    }
...............
```

Comment: How do you want the exception handled?

Comment: Why not use JFormattedTextField?

Comment: well you could try apache commons' NumberUtils which encapsulates that exception handling away from you: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#toDouble%28java.lang.String,%20double%29

Comment: [The docs suggest a rather complex regular expression for validation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String s1 = t1.getText();
    try {
        double x = Double.parseDouble(s1);
    } catch (NumberFormatException  ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Please Enter Proper Number in the t1 TextField");
        return;
    }
    String s2 = t2.getText();

    try {
        double y = Double.parseDouble(s2);
    } catch (NumberFormatException  ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Please Enter Proper Number in the t2 TextField");
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is you who knows how to handle such exceptions in your case. There is no other ways around to get the exceptions handled for you. Your code is correct and that is what done by most programmers. You may use `JFormattedTextField` but however that also doesn't handle exceptions for you.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO No,

If you see [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29)

> public static double parseDouble(String s)
>                             throws NumberFormatException

even if any shortcut   is there it will use the above method and apperently thats also throws the same exception.

Comment: In c#, we have a " int.TryParse(String,out int)" function to try parsing, that returns a bool value.. So, my question is that, is there any predefined method for doing the same..? or what code should i include if i have to define my own function for doing the same..?

Comment: There is no such method, but you could write it. It'd have to catch the Exception and return false if it did. If not, return true and before set an out-Param to the parsing result.

Comment: Thats correct @Baadshah, but he asked for a possibility to have a method like in C# in the comment above. So he can move the try/catch to that method, but he has to do it somewhere, I absolutely agree. I don't know the C#-implementation, but I'd bet, they do it the same way.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid handling exceptions while parsing strings to get numbers (or double, in your case), you can use [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) in conjunction with [ParsePosition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/ParsePosition.html) as shown below:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParsePosition;

public class TestClass
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {     
      System.out.println("Parse test 10.00 ---> " + parseNumber("10.00"));
      System.out.println("Parse test \"\" ---> " + parseNumber(""));
      System.out.println("Parse test 10 ---> " + parseNumber("10"));
      System.out.println("Parse test shgdfhsaghdga ---> " + parseNumber("shgdfhsaghdga"));
   }

   private static boolean parseNumber(String input)
   {
      NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getInstance();
      ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
      fmt.parse(input, pos);
      return input.length() != 0 && (input.length() == pos.getIndex());      
   }

}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Parse test 10.00 ---> true
Parse test "" ---> false
Parse test 10 ---> true
Parse test shgdfhsaghdga ---> false
```

If the number is a valid string, the index of the ParsePosition object will reach the end of the string. Otherwise, it will end at the first invalid position. The last return statement checks this condition. You can use the `parseNumber()` method to prevalidate your string before parsing it to double.